# What is the difference between a pattern and a path?

Tags: symfony

I'm learning Symfony2 and I was wondering what the difference is between a pattern and a path in the demo that contains a "pattern"? I.e.:

```
acme_hello_namespace_homepage:
    pattern:  /hellons/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloNamespaceBundle:Default:index }

hello:
    path:     /hellons/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeHelloNamespaceBundle:Hello:index }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's the same thing, but "pattern" is now deprecated in favor of "path" as you can see here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6738/files#diff-0